# Basic-аутентификация с помощью C#

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace Update
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create("url");
            SetBasicAuthHeader(request, "name", "password");

            var response = request.GetResponse();
        }

        public void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, String userName, String userPassword)
        {
            string authInfo = userName + ":" + userPassword;
            authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
            request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

При выполнении выдаёт ошибку:

> Ошибка    1   Для нестатического поля, метода или свойства "Update.Program.SetBasicAuthHeader(System.Net.WebRequest, string, string)" требуется ссылка на объект  E:\Update\Program.cs    17  13  Update

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо объявить метод `SetBasicAuthHeader` как статический, чтобы можно было вызвать его из другого статического метода без создания объекта.

```
public static void SetBasicAuthHeader(WebRequest request, ...)
{
  ...
}
```